# On phaser2 how to increase the speed of the body with out changing it's direction?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am making a clone of the angrybird game. In this game, I am using the code mentioned below to get the velocity of the bird.

```
getVelocity(mouse) {

        let rangeLine = new Phaser.Line(this.startingPos.x, this.startingPos.y, mouse.x, mouse.y);

        let velocityX = Math.cos(rangeLine.angle + Phaser.Math.degToRad(180)) * rangeLine.length;
        let velocityY = Math.sin(rangeLine.angle + Phaser.Math.degToRad(180)) * rangeLine.length;

        let speedX = velocityX * 6;
        let speedY = velocityY * 6;

        return new Phaser.Point(speedX, speedY);
}
```

Now, I am stuck with how to increase the speed (special power) of the bird in phaser2 engine as mentioned in the below mentioned videos:

https://youtu.be/aiiQ8btusrs?t=587

and also this one
https://youtu.be/aiiQ8btusrs?t=564

Comment: what exactly have you tried? where exactly is your problem? can you share the essential parts of your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want an yellow bird and blue bird superpower on angrybird game in phaser2 engine